# REGEX replace function not working for line break at the end of the string in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the next function:

```
function replaceEnter(str){

  str= str.toString();

  var re = new RegExp(/\r?\n|\r/gm);

  return str.replace(re," ");
}
```

Also tried with

```
function replaceEnter(str){

  str= str.toString();

  var re = new RegExp(/\n/gm);

  return str.replace(re," ");
}
```

I apply it to a value on a cell, and it works perfectly sometimes, but most of the time if the string has a line break at the end of it, the function will skip it.

I use this function to process the text and build a SQL query, so the line breaks break the query.

Example:

```
..code.. +  datosQ[k][4]+"','"+replaceEnter(replaceQuotes(datosQ[k][5]))+"','" + ...more code...
```

The replaceQuotes replaces all quotes or single quotes for an angle quote to avoid problems on the query.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try reading how to use the RegExp function at MDN

Comment: Your example not very useful at the moment. Try writing a sample string(s) with the expected result(s) to illustrate your issue better.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have tested this expression some where to insure that it actually works because I haven't.

Try:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\r?\\n|\\r','gm');
```